# Is the word "project" the only such stress-depending word in English?

Tags: word-request

Is the word "project" the only word in English that has two different meanings depending on where the stress falls?

> I like your pr**O**ject.
>
> We need to proj**E**ct this idea on his program.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun

Comment: Object and subject are others.

Comment: You mean a verb and a noun?

Comment: @Lambie - Not necessarily.

Comment: Well, your example **is that**. The stress differs in the verb or noun. Two words that are written the same and pronounced differently and have different meanings are homonyms, specifically homographs regardless of the number of syllables.

Comment: @Lambie - I know that my example is that. But I did not insist on that.

Comment: Well, it's good to name these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are many: *incense*, *contract*, *permit*, *record*, *concert*, etc.

[An incomplete list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial-stress-derived_noun#List)

There are a few, mostly borrowed words like *résumé* and *divorcé*, that are sometimes written with the accent marks to help distinguish them from the verb/adjective with the same spelling.

(Edit) As FumbleFingers mentions, *in general* the noun has the accent on the first syllable, while the verb/adjective has the accent on the second (or last) syllable, e.g. *CONtract* vs *conTRACT.*  However, as is typical in English, there are exceptions: *mentor* is pronounced the same for both the noun and the verb, and (as HiddenBabel mentions) some pronounce *detail* with the accent on the first syllable, and some with the accent on the second syllable, and some both ways depending on context.

Comment: I remember one person pronouncing the name of Kyra Sedgwick's show as if it were "more close".

Comment: I'm think it's at least *usually* the case that the specific difference is the (original?) verb form has *stress on the **second** syllable*, which we shift to the first syllable when using as a noun. But how solidly does that rule apply? And are there any examples of relatively recent new words that only started life as either verbs ***or*** nouns, but which have now extended to the other sense? Specifically, suppose a 2-syllable neologism started out as a noun with 2nd-syllable stress, or as a verb with 1st-syllable stress? How would this "rule" apply in *those* cases (if they even exist! :)

Comment: "Detail" is another exception. The verb is stressed on the first syllable, while the noun can be stressed on either syllable depending on the speaker.